# Getting this error when using npm start command in terminal in Visual Code

Tags: reactjs

```
npm : The term 'npm' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check   
the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ npm start
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (npm:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

while starting REACT app in browser using npm start

Comment: Have you installed node on system

Comment: yes I have installed, could not open browser through npm start command from terminal in visual code

Comment: Can you check with `npm -v` and tell the output

Comment: npm -v
npm : The term 'npm' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check   
the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ npm -v
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (npm:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: Probably not installed correctly...Install Node from here again: https://nodejs.org/en/

Comment: yes reinstalled nodejs and changed environment variables now working fine thank you